# C# async await in Swift

Tags: c#, swift, asynchronous, async-await, closures

I'm currently playing with closures and chained completions in `Swift`. I'm quite familiar with the `C#` style of `async` and `await`, so I was wondering how to "translate" the following snippet from `C#` to `Swift`.

```
public async Task SomeFunction(string inputString)
{
    var first = await GetFirstVariableAsync(inputString);
    var second = await GetSecondVariableAsync(first);

    if (second == "some condition")
    {
        first = await GetFirstVariableAsync(inputString);
        var second = await GetSecondVariableAsync(first);
    }
}
```

Does `Swift` has a similar construct like `await`, to wait for a function to complete, without having to nest multiple completion blocks?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaking, what are you looking for is:

**Serial Dispatch Queues:**

> Serial queues (also known as private dispatch queues) execute one task
>   at a time in the order in which they are added to the queue. The
>   currently executing task runs on a distinct thread (which can vary
>   from task to task) that is managed by the dispatch queue. Serial
>   queues are often used to synchronize access to a specific resource.
>   You can create as many serial queues as you need, and each queue
>   operates concurrently with respect to all other queues. In other
>   words, if you create four serial queues, each queue executes only one
>   task at a time but up to four tasks could still execute concurrently,
>   one from each queue. For information on how to create serial queues,
>   see Creating Serial Dispatch Queues.

Swift 3:

```
let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "serialQueue")

serialQueue.sync {
    print("running first task")
}

serialQueue.sync {
    print("I will wait the first task and then I'll do my own task")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - is it possible to access parameters in different "queue items"?

Answer (score 2):

Currently `concurrency in Swift language` is not there yet. It's still a proposal for `Swift 5` on [Swift evolution](http://swift%20evolution%20mailing%20list) and here is link of it: [concurrency proposal](https://gist.github.com/lattner/31ed37682ef1576b16bca1432ea9f782). But If this time you are developing apps using `Cocoa`/`Cocoa touch` then you can use [Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch), but I think it's has ugly syntax. I am still looking for concurrency in `Swift` language

Answer (score 0):

You can use this framework for Swift coroutines - https://github.com/belozierov/SwiftCoroutine

```
func awaitAPICall(_ url: URL) throws -> String? {
    let future = URLSession.shared.dataTaskFuture(for: url)
    let data = try future.await().data
    return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
}

func load(url: URL) {
    DispatchQueue.main.startCoroutine {
        let result1 = try self.awaitAPICall(url)
        let result2 = try self.awaitAPICall2(result1)
        let result3 = try self.awaitAPICall3(result2)
        print(result3)
    }
}
```